# How to Copy Magento live site to localserver?

Tags: magento-1.9

I got error when type 'http://localhost/allgoodrange/index.php' then the path will automatic change like 'https://allgoodrange.com

how i do in my site.

Comment: Rajesh, can you explain your situation a little better? Plus also write a better title to suit your question. What is the exact problem: Does index.php redirect to /? Or is there an error? (code errors in screen). Did you update Base url: https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-change-magento-base-urls.html

Answer (score 1):

Go to the `core_config_data` table and look up entries matching `LIKE 'web%url'`. These entries must have your local environment's URLs.